# Postgres: Downsampling for every 2 hours?

Tags: sql, postgresql, downsampling

I've been trying to downsample my data in postgres, to mimic the downsampling that python offers (using 'resample').

so far I've managed to do it for single units of time as:

```
SELECT t,avg(data)
FROM
(
    SELECT date_trunc('hour',"timestamp") as t,*
    FROM
    (
        SELECT "timestamp",data
        FROM sample_data
    )res1
ORDER BY t
)res
GROUP BY t
```

which groups for every 1 hour.

what if I wish to downsample for every 2 hours/5 hours etc ?

Comment: if you know the lower and upper bonds you can `generate_series(min,max,'2 hours'::interval)` and join against it